# Link Wordpress post images to post

Tags: php, wordpress

I'm developing a wordpress theme for my blog and I'm having some difficulty.

When I make a new post, the first image of that post is displayed on the homepage. When the image is clicked, it links to the image file and shows the full size. I would like for it to automatically link to the post from which it came. I understand that you can choose what the image links to upon upload or in the editor. I would like for the images to link to their original post automatically, since I have other people writing on my blog, and I don't want them to have to do this each time.

As I understand it the content.php file controls the post format in this case. Here is the file from my theme. Or is it possible to use a function?

```
    <?php
/**
 * The default template for displaying content single/search/archive
 *
 * @package test
 * @since test 0.1.0
 */
?>
    <!-- START: content.php -->
    <article id="post-<?php the_ID(); ?>" <?php post_class(); ?>>
        <header class="entry-header">
            <?php if ( is_single() ) : ?>
            <h1 class="entry-title"><?php the_title(); ?></h1>
            <?php else : ?>
            <?php the_post_thumbnail(); ?>
            <h1 class="entry-title">
                <a href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>" title="<?php echo esc_attr( sprintf( __( 'Permalink to %s', 'test' ), the_title_attribute( 'echo=0' ) ) ); ?>" rel="bookmark"><?php the_title(); ?></a>
            </h1>
            <?php endif; // is_single() ?>
        </header><!-- .entry-header -->
        <?php if ( 'post' == get_post_type() ) : ?>
        <div class="entry-meta">
            <?php posted_on(); ?>
            <?php if ( is_sticky() && is_home() && ! is_paged() ) : ?>
            <span class="label radius secondary"><a href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>" title="<?php printf( esc_attr__( 'Permalink to %s', 'test' ), the_title_attribute( 'echo=0' ) ); ?>" rel="bookmark"><?php _ex( 'Featured', 'Post format title', 'test' ); ?></a></span>
            <?php endif; ?>
        </div><!-- .entry-meta -->
        <?php endif; ?>
        <?php if ( is_search() ) : // Only display Excerpts for Search ?>
        <div class="entry-summary">
            <?php the_excerpt(); ?>
        </div><!-- .entry-summary -->
        <?php else : ?>
        <div class="entry-content">
            <?php the_content( __( 'Continue reading <span class="meta-nav">&rarr;</span>', 'test' ) ); ?>
            <?php wp_link_pages( array( 'before' => '<div class="page-link"><span>' . __( 'Pages:', 'test' ) . '</span>', 'after' => '</div>' ) ); ?>
        </div><!-- .entry-content -->
        <?php endif; ?>

        <footer class="entry-meta">
            <?php if ( 'post' == get_post_type() ) : ?>
            <?php get_template_part('entry-meta', get_post_format() ); ?>
            <?php endif; ?>
        </footer><!-- #entry-meta -->

    </article><!-- #post-<?php the_ID(); ?> -->
    <!-- END: content.php -->
```

Answer (score 0):

https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/the_post_thumbnail
example 1. To link Post Thumbnails to the Post Permalink in a specific loop, use the following within your Theme's template files:

```
<?php if ( has_post_thumbnail()) : ?>
  <a href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>" title="<?php the_title_attribute(); ?>" >
    <?php the_post_thumbnail(); ?>
  </a>
<?php endif; ?>
```

Comment: Thanks for you answer. I figured it out using the info. I changed the_content to the_excerpt, then moved the post thumb into the href link attribute for the title tag. This allows for the thumbnail and title to be one link together.